# How to build multiple packages from a single python module using pyproject.toml and poetry?

Tags: python, setup.py, python-packaging, python-poetry, pyproject.toml

I want to achieve a similar behavior as the library Dask does, it is possible to use `pip` to install `dask`, `dask[dataframe]`, `dask[array]` and others. They do it by using the `setup.py` with a packages key [like this](https://github.com/dask/dask/blob/a7e57ba9ea65700a531a8d5e637f5d580e2d34e3/setup.py#L43). If I install only `dask` the `dask[dataframe]` is not installed and they warn you about this when executing the module.

I found [this](https://python-poetry.org/docs/pyproject/#packages) in the poetry documentation but when I execute `poetry build` I only get one `.whl` file with all of the packages within.

**How can I package my module to be able to install specific parts of a library using `poetry`?**

Comment: You need to look up [_`extras`_](https://python-poetry.org/docs/pyproject/#extras). And yes, it is normal to get only one _wheel `.whl`_ file.

Comment: But _`extras`_ do not allow to optionally install some specific parts of the library. It only allows to optionally install some dependencies of the library.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Actually the Dask example does not install subpackages separately, it just installs the custom dependencies separately as explained in [this link](https://docs.dask.org/en/stable/install.html#pip).

In order to accomplish the same behavior using `poetry` you need to use [this](https://python-poetry.org/docs/pyproject/#extras) (as mentioned by user @sinoroc in [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71497081/how-to-build-multiple-packages-from-a-single-python-module-using-pyproject-toml#comment126371167_71497081))

The example `pyproject.toml` from the `poetry` extras page is this:

```
[tool.poetry]
name = "awesome"

[tool.poetry.dependencies]
# These packages are mandatory and form the core of this package’s distribution.
mandatory = "^1.0"

# A list of all of the optional dependencies, some of which are included in the
# below `extras`. They can be opted into by apps.
psycopg2 = { version = "^2.7", optional = true }
mysqlclient = { version = "^1.3", optional = true }

[tool.poetry.extras]
mysql = ["mysqlclient"]
pgsql = ["psycopg2"]
```

By using `poetry build --format wheel` a single wheel file would be created.

In order to install a specific set of extra dependencies using pip and the wheel file you should use:

```
pip install "wheel_filename.whl[mysql]"
```